# How can I incorporate functions and methods into my if-else conditions in Java?

Tags: java, function, if-statement, input

I am able to run a program that calculates the perimeter of a shape and uses if-else conditions to determine what shape it is. However, I am struggling to pair my if-else conditions with functions and methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sideA;
    int sideB;
    int sideC;
    int sideD;
    int perimeter = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter side 1: ");
    sideA = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 2: ");
    sideB = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 3: ");
    sideC = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 4: ");
    sideD = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Forms a square with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    System.out.println("Forms a rectangle with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    System.out.println("Does not form a rectangle or square.");
}

private static int add(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD) {     
    int perimeter = sideA + sideB + sideC + sideD;
    return perimeter;
}

private static void isSquare(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD, int perimeter) {
if (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC && sideC == sideD && sideD == sideA) {
        System.out.println("Forms a square with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    }

    else if (sideA == sideC && sideB == sideD) {
        System.out.println("Forms a rectangle with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
      }

    else if (sideA == sideB && sideC == sideD) {
        System.out.println("Forms a rectangle with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
      }

    else if (sideA == sideD && sideB == sideC) {
        System.out.println("Forms a rectangle with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
      }

    else {
        System.out.println("Does not form a rectangle or square.");
    }
}
```

The program I'm working on now has problems with reaching the end of its file while parsing. How do I improve that end of the file so that my program completes its parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, you should just call your methods from the `main` method:

```
// code inside main
    // remove line System.out.println("Forms a square with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    // remove line System.out.println("Forms a rectangle with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    // remove line System.out.println("Does not form a rectangle or square.");
    perimeter = add(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);
    isSquare(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD, perimeter);  // this method prints results

// end of main method
```

Please also make sure that all your code is wrapped into some class :)

Answer (score 0):

i mean you should think about calling your methods add and isSquare 
maybe move your variables outside of main so they have more scope

```
    add(sideA,sideB,sideC,sideD);
    isSquare(sideA,sideB,sideC,sideD,perimeter);
```

Comment: This code will print `with a perimeter of 0` for square or rectangle

Comment: There are a few other things that need to be changed
perimeter is declared in main but nothing happens with it 
we could do 
       perimeter = add(sideA, sideB,sideC,sideD, perimeter);

Answer (score 0):

You have no files here. But as I understand you correctly you should call your functions from main method
`System.out.println("Forms a square with a perimeter of " + add(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);`, also `sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC && sideC == sideD && sideD == sideA` the same that `sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC && sideC == sideD` (transitivity a=b=c => a=c)